# Dynamic fragments opened with buttons - but app crashes (android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I followed a tutorial to be able to create an activity with two buttons which should then open two fragments (so the fragment first opened is replaced by the second one opened) - However my app crashes.
My code is

public class Play extends MainActivity {

```
@Override                                                                                       
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                            
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);                                                     


    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {                                          
        @Override                                                                               
        public void onClick(View v) {                                                           

            FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();                                     
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();                         
            Fragment fragment1;                                                                 

            if(v == findViewById(R.id.imageButton10)) {                                         
                fragment1 = new FragmentOne();                                                  
            } else {                                                                            
                fragment1 = new FragmentTwo();                                                  
            }                                                                                   

            fragTrans.replace(R.id.output, fragment1);                                          
            fragTrans.commit();                                                                 

        }                                                                                       
    };                                                                                          

    ImageButton imageBtn10 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);                     
    imageBtn10.setOnClickListener(listener);                                                    
    ImageButton imageBtn9 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);                       
    imageBtn9.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

}

And the fragments are basically identical (with names changed etc)

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
    TextView output = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    output.setText("Fragment One");
    return v;
}
```

}

The XML file for Play has a bunch of imagebuttons and then the fragment as:

```
<fragment
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="188dp"
       android:id="@+id/output" />
```

How come it crashes?

Comment: If you want help on a crash, post the full stack trace of the crash.

Comment: @GabeSechan I tried and it came up with 
01/05 22:52:46: Launching app
...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
E/EGL_emulation: tid 5569: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9f1e1e20, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH